# C++ jump into different DLL

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, assembly, dll

In my project i want C++ to jump or goto an address, which appears to be another function in a different dll file.

Here is my code so far

```
void* interceptor(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, ...){
    ...

    // get the function address
    void* originalfunc = bindingmap[method];

    //   restoring stack pointer and other critical registors
    asm (
        "mov %ebp, %esp;"
        "mov %rbp, %rsp;"
        "mov 0x10(%rbp), %rcx;"
        "mov 0x20(%rbp), %r8;"
        "mov 0x28(%rbp), %r9;"
        "mov 0x18(%rbp), %rdx;"
    );

    asm volatile("jmp *%0;"::"r" (originalfunc+4));
    //  goto *(originalfunc+4);
}
```

Here when I enter the interceptor method, i am retrieving a void* pointer to a function, then i restore all the critical registers and then i jump the function...

At this point i get a problem, that it only works if my target function is in the same dll file as my interceptor function. If i try to jump into another DLL, i get a segmantation fault...

Does anybody have an idea of what is going wrong here and why?

Comment: i think you will be much better off using windows supported mechanisms for dynamically calling things, getprocaddress

Comment: how would i do that? I am not that knowligible in this area :(

Comment: example right here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why can't you just call through a function pointer and let the compiler handle it?

Comment: @Cody because i intercept many methods and resolve their addresses dynamically in the runtime...

Comment: …so? If you have their addresses, then you can call them through that pointer. I mean, the compiler needs to know the calling convention, what parameters they take, and all that business, but you *also* need to know that if you're going to write the calls in assembly.

Comment: well , i am trying to avoid resolving parameters with the varargs and jump... meaning, interceptor would just pass all of its parameters to a resolved function... I already have tried a lo0t of different other approaches ... like complicated typedefs or third parties which would compile code at runtime, but nothing worked

Comment: Yes, you've found out that writing a universal hook library is not easy. If it were easy, everyone would do it and Microsoft Research wouldn't have needed to write [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) (and wouldn't be able to sell it for big $$). Anyway, the interceptor cannot just pass all of its parameters to the resolved function unless the resolved function has *exactly the same signature/prototype*, and if that's true, then just `typedef` that and let the C compiler generate the call through the function pointer, as I said.

Comment: Doing a `jmp` out of a function is not a good idea: The function may for example do a `push` instruction and later do a `pop` instruction...